# How can i open another window from my second link?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have created some code with one link. When i click at the link #1 a pop up windows comes up with some text/html in it. You can see the example here: http://johnnylai.me/popup

How can i make sure to get another pop up window when i click at link #2 with different text/html in it? and so on with link #3 and #4?

```
HTML & jQuery code:
<code>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Popup Examples</title>
<link href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/css/jquerysctipttop.css" rel="stylesheet">   
<link href="dist/magnific-popup.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="dist/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

<a class="popup-with-zoom-anim" href="#small-dialog">#1 - fade-zoom animation</a><br>
<br>
<a class="popup-with-zoom-anim1" href="#small-dialog">#2 - fade-zoom animation</a><br>

<div id="small-dialog" class="mfp-hide">
<h1>Dialog example1</h1>
<p>This is dummy copy. It is not meant to be read. It has been placed here solely to   demonstrate the look and feel of finished, typeset text. Only for show. He who searches for meaning here will be sorely disappointed.</p>
</div>

<div id="small-dialog" class="mfp-hide">
<h1>Dialog example2</h1>
<p>This is dummy copy. It is not meant to be read. It has been placed here solely to demonstrate the look and feel of finished, typeset text. Only for show. He who searches for meaning here will be sorely disappointed.</p>
</div>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.popup-with-zoom-anim').magnificPopup({
        type: 'inline',

        fixedContentPos: false,
        fixedBgPos: true,

        overflowY: 'auto',

        closeBtnInside: true,
        preloader: false,

        midClick: true,
        removalDelay: 300,
        mainClass: 'my-mfp-zoom-in'
    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>

</code>
```

Comment: Show us your code. What have tried till now and what is it that's not working?

Comment: Ok i will, i just thought you would see the source code the by right click at the page, just a sec..

Comment: I've taken a look at the code and it seems to use a javascript library of some sort to show the 'popups'. Also your links have the same ID. 

Big -1. It doesn't even validate! Do this first: http://validator.w3.org/ and then show us a jsfiddle.

Comment: Not sure to understand what you want exactly.

Comment: Note sure but can you try anchor attribute target="_blank".

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the `1` in your second link. Keep class name the same. Change the `href ID` of second to match the `ID of the div` you would like to target.

**UPDATE: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jUdL5/2/)**

```
<a class="popup-with-zoom-anim" href="#small-dialog">#1 - fade-zoom animation</a><br><br>
<a class="popup-with-zoom-anim" href="#small-dialog2">#2 - fade-zoom animation</a><br>

<div id="small-dialog2" class="mfp-hide">
<h1>Dialog example2</h1>
<p>This is dummy copy. It is not meant to be read. It has been placed here solely to demonstrate   the look and feel of finished, typeset text. Only for show. He who searches for meaning here will be sorely disappointed.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Works fine: **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jUdL5/1/)** (disregard the messed up css) Please make sure you followed my steps correctly. If anything is unclear. Please let me know.

Comment: It seems to work in jsFiddle, but there's no new window poping up, it just blur the foreground in a dark color.

I have updated the code as you have descibed on my website. Pls. check it out. No pop up window.

Comment: Its working, the rest is styling issues related to the plugin. You might want to check in with the developers of the plugin as to why the styles are not working properly. OR read plugin documentation for some guidance.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <a class="popup-with-zoom-anim" href="#small-dialog">
```

the #small-dialog is the link to the div you want to show - change one of the div id and update one of the link

Comment: As you see in the answer to Shivam, it didn't help to add another id to the href.

Comment: the <a> tags need to have different id - and the 2 <div> other id ; in the href attribute u gonna call the id of the two different divs. It works @Shivam make u a JSfiddle